# get next page number instead of next page link django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I'm working with **django rest framework** but I face this problem with **the pagination** the output Show in next and previous the page link but I want the page number only

my pagination.py

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class MycustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10
    page_query_param = 'page'
```

my views.py

```
from  .paginations import MMycustomPagination

class AllSerialed(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = MycustomPagination
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(blacklist=False).order_by("-date")
    serializer_class = MyModelSerial
```

simple output

```
{
    "count": 20,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:7000/data/?page=3",
    "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:7000/data/?page=1",
    "results": [
               ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `get_paginated_response` method in your pagination class to handle that like they do in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#example) but modifying the `next` and `previous` values:

```py
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class MycustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10
    page_query_param = 'page'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'next': self.page.next_page_number() if self.page.has_next() else None,
            'previous': self.page.previous_page_number() if self.page.has_previous() else None,
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })
```

Let's think that your `pagination.py` file is located in `project_folder/app_name/pagination.py`. You can set this custom pagination style gloabally by setting the key `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` in the `REST_FRAMEWORK` variable to:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ... # other keys you may be using
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'app_name.pagination.MycustomPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5
}
```

in your `settings.py` file. If you want to add it manually to your views you can specify `pagination_class = MycustomPagination` like you are already doing in your `views.py` file.

Comment: I'm just using it for specific view thank u that's exactly what i was looking for ❤️